# Run a ubuntu file in windows as executable file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have made a python file and converted it to executable file with pyinstaller in Ubuntu, now I want to run the same executable file in windows, how would I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can. You need convert you `.py` file to `.exe` in windows again.

Comment: You need tools that make it to an exe file, like cxFreeze or py2exe

Comment: Can you convert it to exe on windows from your original python file?

Comment: I know that I can convert the .py file to .exe in windows with pye2exe etc. but I don't want to download python etc in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Oups... Programs exists in different formats, normally text (.py for Python), byte code (.pyc) for Python and native executable formats. Text is normally portable across any architecture except for possible charset conversions. Byte code is normally portable, I am sure for Java, less for Python because I have never used it. But native executable formats (true executable in Linux or .exe files on Windows) are dedicated to one single architecture.

So a program generated by pyinstaller on Ubuntu can only be used on a Linux system with same system libraries as yours (read Ubuntu same version, even if it should also run on some other Linux flavours), but definitely not on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install pyinstaller on windows, and run pyinstaller on windows (From the OS that you want to build your exe file)